# Does a Yemeni citizen need transit visa to connect in Mumbai, India?

Tags: india, transit-visas, connecting-flights, yemeni-citizens

I am a Yemen citizen and want to travel from Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia to Muscat, Oman as follows:

- Kuala Lumpur to Mumbai via Malindo Air
- 5 hour 40 minutes layover before connection
- Mumbai to Muscat via Oman Air

I am traveling with two flights that are booked separately. Is the connection time enough and do I need a transit visa for Mumbai ?

If I book on Skyscanner with the same two airlines, does it work the same if I book the same flights myself?

Comment: If you are booked on separate tickets, your luggage will  probably not be checked through and you will have to reclaim and check it in at BOM. For this you'll need a visa. But Oman air and Malindo seem to have an interline agreement and it is possible they may check your luggage through to Muscat. In that case you can transit Mumbai without a visa. Your best bet is to call malindo and confirm if your luggage can be checked through.

Comment: @RedBaron , thanks for your comment , that confirms what I heard from my friend , I will check with the airline then update with an answer ..

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IN&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (**T**ransit **W**ith**o**ut **V**isa): Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

TWOV normally means **not** clearing immigration, including in India - thus you cannot TWOV if having baggage to pick up (which, with separate bookings, you have to).

Furthermore, even if you only have hand luggage, at most airports check-in staff requires the trip to be in a single booking in order to board you on the basis of TWOV. This is in part because if something happens to your connection, you're not "insured" for the rest of your trip and the airline that took you to Mumbai may have to send you back if you can't pay to have the connection re-booked.

**So yes, you will need a transit visa**

Answer (score 1):

Careful with the tickets! Mumbai has different airports. If you have to change terminals or change airports then you will definitely need a transit visa.

In fact, changing airports would be a big hassle. Double check on your ticket.

Comment: ooh ture! , I will book using Skyscanner, do you have idea if they connect flights with same airport or terminal or not ?

Comment: Sorry but all international flights depart from same terminal T2 in Mumbai. The answer is factually incorrect and also does not answer the actual question. -1. Please modify the answer and I'll redact the vote.

Comment: Can you please quote your reference? As far as I know only JetAirways/Etihad depart from T2

Comment: Al-yaseen Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't. Usually if you buy a single ticket or have an international connection then they do. But you mentioned that you are buying separate tickets and that's why I wanted to make you cautious.

Comment: See [the official site](http://www.csia.in/passenger/check-in-process-int-dep.aspx). Since 2015 even domestic operators have shifted to T2. Only LCC domestic carriers depart from Terminal-1.