# Does a Yemeni citizen need a transit visa for India?

Tags: visas, india, transit-visas, yemeni-citizens

I will travel from Aden to Mumbai by Yemen Airways, and then I will travel to Kuala Lumpur by Malaysia Airlines. Do I need an Indian visa for the connection?

Comment: Not an expert but I think this thread addresses this well:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100171/does-a-yemeni-citizen-need-transit-visa-to-connect-in-mumbai-india